# How to test controller with nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Please help solve this problem. I need a testing render template for the index action.

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums
end
```

rake routes:

```
user_albums GET    /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)             albums#index
```

albums controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :get_album_data]

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @albums = @user.albums.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 6).order(created_at: :DESC)
    @album = Album.new
  end

  .........
  .........

  private
    def set_album
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:title, :description)
    end   
end
```

albums_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe AlbumsController do
      describe 'index action' do
        it 'render index template if user is found' do
          user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
          get :index, { user_id: user.id }
          response.should render_template('index')
        end
      end
    end
```

factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'qqq'
    sequence(:email){ |i| "use#{i}@ad.ad" }
    password 'qwerty'
    password_confirmation{ |u| u.password } 
  end
end
```

I run it in the console:

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
rspec spec
```

Console displays the following error messages:

```
F.

Failures:

  1) AlbumsController index action render index template if user is found
     Failure/Error: get :index, { user_id: user.id }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController::IndexAction:0x000000067fc668>
     # ./spec/controllers/albums_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.13261 seconds (files took 1.91 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/albums_controller_spec.rb:5 # AlbumsController index action render index template if user is found
```

Please help me with the 'index' testing action

Comment: Is your `albums_controller_spec.rb` missing `require 'rails-helper'`?

Comment: (`spec-helper`) for older versions of RSpec-rails

Comment: it is in my file. I just do not have the issue of

Comment: [stackoverflow drive development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023392/how-testing-the-devise-model-via-rspec) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current error you're getting

```
undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController
```

is because you need to specify your spec as a controller spec with type: :controller.

```
describe AlbumsController, type: :controller do
```